# Dynamically check checkbox after loading the page in html using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am coding a page that contains checkboxes. the user check some of them and their values are stored in some table. Now if the user again visit that page then previously stored values are read for the table. Now I want to check those boxes whose values are stored and the remaining remains unchecked. Can anybody help me ? thanks in advance..

Comment: `Can anybody help me ? ` NO!!!!!.. not unless we see your related code....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //Read table

    //Check appropriate checkboxed
    $('#Your CheckBox ID ').attr('checked', 'checked');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //Read table

    //Check appropriate checkboxed
    $('#cb2').attr('checked', 'checked');
});
```

Comment: I guess your answer wasn't good enough; I guess it had to be copy/ pasted first to get accepted!

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty easy using `.prop()` or `.attr()`

```
$('.some-selector-for-radio-or-checkbox').prop('checked', true);
```